# Jar class path dependency versions are getting overridden by spark system class path jars resulting NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, jar, dependencies, guava, nosuchmethoderror

I have a Jar with **Guava v16 as a dependency**, and when we deployed the Jar to a **Spark cluster (v2.3.2)** the Guava v16 getting **replaces by Guava v28** which causing issues like **NoSuchMethodError** Exception. **Anyone know how to force the spark to use v16 in this case ?**

`Note: We have tried by changing the build with options such as compile,runtime,runtimeClassPath,strict version,resolutionStrategy also by submitting the Guava v19 as a jar to spark while running original jar file`